# How can i free all what i allocated in this code? why it's case of segmentation fault?

Tags: c, memory

someone can explain me how can i free all what i allocated in this code?
i get error of "segmentation fault" and I don't understand what i don't freed here?

```
void FreeMatrix(int*** matrix, int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        free((*matrix)[i]);
    }
    free(*matrix);
}


int main() {
    AddColumn(a, size1, &size2, newCol, size1);
    PrintMatrix(*a, size1, size2);
}
```

Thank you for your help.
I jus ask for how to free all of what i allocated, the code is working. I tried a lot of things for fix this problem and i don't know how to do it, so i will be very happy for help from one of you.

Comment: Probably interesting read: http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: If you get a crash, then use a *debugger* to catch it and locate where it happens. Also use tools such as Valgrind to help you find problems with out-of-bounds writing and other memory-/pointer-related errors.

Comment: As a side-note, don't do `int*** a = ...` and pass `a` straight of. Use e.g. `int** a` and use `&a` to pass a pointer to `a`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your tip, but it's still not fixed.

Comment: It sounds like you believe you get a segmentation fault from not freeing all memory. But this is usually not the case, what you get are memory leaks, but the code should still run. Only when your process has no more available memory, and you don't check the return value of `malloc`, could a segmentation fault be caused from a memory leak. Nevertheless, you should still tell us which line causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: Adding a column to `a` does not add a row to `b`. After adding the column the value of `size2` is incremented and used to free the rows of `b`. This tries to free one more row than what is available

Comment: _'i get error of "segmentation fault"'_ When? And have you tried using a debugger to trace back from that mysterious point?

Comment: the root of the problem is the first call to malloc in BuildMatrix(), that allocates room for the pointers to the rows of data. Each of those pointers will contain trash until initialized. So either 1) use calloc() for the first call or 2) use memset() to initialize everything to '\0' after the first call. When an error occurs in the call to malloc() and the code is trying to cleanup, the free() function is currently being passed trash for any/all uninitialized entries. By using calloc() or memset(), any uninitialized entries will contain NULL. Passing NULL to free() is not a problem

Comment: @user3629249 All pointers to the rows are initialized using `malloc`. If it fails, the previous rows are freed and with `*matrix=NULL` the matrix is cleared as well. I can't see how you get uninitialized pointers during building the matrix.

Comment: @Gerhardh,  NOT true.  When some call to `malloc()` fails, the code returns from the current function, It does not cleanup, it does not exit.

Comment: @user3629249 The loop after `if ((*matrix)[i] == NULL) {` does exactly that cleanup.

Comment: In addition to the problem with changing `size2`, in `AddColumn()` the call to `realloc` could return `NULL`, invalidating your pointer in the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Three-star programming is usually a danger sign...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you are changing the value of variable `size2` after creating matrix `b` with the initial value of `size2` as number of rows.

```
int size1 = 2, size2 = 3, size3 = 2;
```

then you are doing:

```
BuildMatrix(b, size2, size3);
```

This will create matrix `b` of dimension - `3`x`2`.
After this you are doing:

```
AddColumn(a, size1, &size2, newCol, size1);
```

In `AddColumn()` you are changing the value of `size2` variable:

```
void AddColumn(int*** matrix, int row, int* column, int* newCol, int rows) {
```

Pointer `column` hold the address of `size2` and in `AddColumn()` the value of `size2` is incremented by `1`:

```
(*column)++;
```

Now the value of `size2` is `4`.

And when freeing matrix `b`, you are passing the new value of `size2` (which is `4`) to `FreeMatrix()`:

```
FreeMatrix(b, size2);
```

In the `FreeMatrix()`, the `for` loop iterate for `4` times but the matrix `b` is having `3` rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    free((*matrix)[i]);
}
```

In the fourth iteration, some invalid value passed as pointer to `free()`. This is undefined behavior, in your case you are getting segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

regarding: *i get error of "segmentation fault" and I don't understand what i don't freed here?*

Not freeing some allocated memory will NOT cause a seg fault event.

Trying to free some area that was not allocated WILL cause a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation Fault means that your program did something that caused it to crash, like trying to access protected memory. When you don't free everything your program won't crash and you will only see, that you didn't freed everything by running a analyzer like valgrind over it.